# How to skip plugin update prompt when running GRAILS run-app?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-plugin

Started a new project using Grails RC3
(Windows 7 64 bit Java 1.6)

Installed spring-security-core plugin

Now whenever i do a GRAILS run-app it prompts me to upgrade webxml-1.4 to 1.3.1 over and over again

I use IntelliJ 10.5.3 and the console does not let me type NO so I can't use the IDE to debug.

Possible solutions I see in order of preference
- Find a way to skip the plugin upgrade question
- Manually modify the spring-security-core config somewhere to depend on webxml 1.4
- Switch to STS to develop (Console works in STS)

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try setting the --non-interactive flag, which should skip prompts.

```
grails run-app --non-interactive
```

You can manage plugin dependencies in grails by setting this BuildConfig.groovy. See the plugin exclusions section in the User Guide -

http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.7.10%20Plugin%20Dependencies

Just remember to remove the plugin reference from application.properties

Note: for grails 1.3.7 `grails --non-interactive  run-app` will not work the switch has to come after the command as above.

Comment: Finally got it working after flushing the user/grails/project directory in Windows and of course a grails clean. Extra thanks for the application.properties removal notice as IntelliJ adds it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this without using `--non-interactive` is to configure this in `scripts/`.

Add this block to `scripts/_Events.groovy`:

```
def resolveDependenciesWasInteractive = false
eventResolveDependenciesStart = {
    resolveDependenciesWasInteractive = isInteractive
    isInteractive = false
}

eventResolveDependenciesEnd = {
    isInteractive = resolveDependenciesWasInteractive
}
```

Taken from: http://ldaley.com/post/2616518761/disabling-grails-plugin-upgrade-confirmation