# grails prject builds on mac but not on linux

Tags: linux, macos, grails

I hava grails app that I can build on my mac (10.8.4), but not on my linux box (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)). I am getting the following error on linux:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17
grails compile
| Environment set to development.....
> You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [webxml-1.4.1]. Do you want to update to [webxml-1.4]? [y,n] y
| Resolving plugin JAR dependencies.....
> You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [webxml-1.4]. Do you want to update to [webxml-1.4.1]? [y,n] y
| Resolving plugin JAR dependencies.....
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: srcdir "/data1/app/project/target/2.1.4/plugins/webxml-1.4/src/groovy" does not exist! (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Stack trace does not provide any more useful information. I do not get this on my mac. Both systmes have grails 2.1.4. I only see that mac has java 1.6.0_51, as opposed to 1.6.0_17 on linux, but it does not seem likely to be the source of the problem. Any suggestions how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean `/data1/app/project/target/2.1.4/plugins/` manually then try running
`grails clean && grails compile`

Plus select `no` to one of the prompt about `webxml` if you get any.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I also found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375636/how-to-skip-plugin-update-prompt-when-running-grails-run-app) on how to make this work in non interactive mode.